# Python Tornado - making POST return immediately while async function keeps working

Tags: python, tornado

so I have a handler below:

```
class PublishHandler(BaseHandler):

    def post(self):
        message = self.get_argument("message")
        some_function(message)
        self.write("success")
```

The problem that I'm facing is that some_function() takes some time to execute and I would like the post request to return straight away when called and for some_function() to be executed in another thread/process if possible.

I'm using berkeley db as the database and what I'm trying to do is relatively simple.

I have a database of users each with a filter. If the filter matches the message, the server will send the message to the user. Currently I'm testing with thousands of users and hence upon each publication of a message via a post request it's iterating through thousands of users to find a match. This is my naive implementation of doing things and hence my question. How do I do this better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be able to accomplish this by using your `IOLoop`'s `add_callback` method like so:

```
loop.add_callback(lambda: some_function(message))
```

Tornado will execute the callback in the next IOLoop pass, which *may* (I'd have to dig into Tornado's guts to know for sure, or alternatively test it) allow the request to complete before that code gets executed.

The drawback is that that long-running code you've written will still take time to execute, and this may end up blocking another request.  That's not ideal if you have a lot of these requests coming in at once.

The more foolproof solution is to run it in a separate thread or process.  The *best* way with Python is to use a process, due to the GIL (I'd highly recommend reading up on that if you're not familiar with it).  However, on a single-processor machine the threaded implementation will work just as fine, and may be simpler to implement.

If you're going the threaded route, you can build a nice "async executor" module with a mutex, a thread, and a queue.  Check out the `multiprocessing` module if you want to go the route of using a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this, and I believe the request does not complete before the callbacks are called.

I think a dirty hack would be to call two levels of add_callback, e.g.:

```
  def get(self):
    ...
    def _defered():
      ioloop.add_callback(<whatever you want>)
    ioloop.add_callback(_defered)
    ...
```

But these are hacks at best. I'm looking for a better solution right now, probably will end up with some message queue or simple thread solution.